# Making a class, put in dictionary then in list

Tags: python, list, class, dictionary

my 1st question.

How can I make a script with a class(with atributes), then put those atributes in a dictionary, then that dictionary in a list. I tried many options, but cant get it "good" or "efficient" or the right output.

I want to access certain atributes, here is what i got (dont mind the names, its for testing)

```
exercise_list = []
exercise_dict = {}


class Exercises(object):

    def __init__(self, amount, category, info):

        self.amount = amount
        self.category = category
        self.info = info
        exercise_dict.__setitem__("amount", self.amount)
        exercise_dict.__setitem__("category", self.category)
        exercise_dict.__setitem__("info", self.info)
        exercise_list.append(exercise_dict)


Exercises(10, "arm", "Arm curls")
Exercises(20, "legs", "Squats")

print(exercise_list)
print(exercise_list[0])
print(exercise_list[1])
```

The output is not really what i wanted, the list gets overwritten:

```
[{'amount': 20, 'category': 'legs', 'info': 'Squats'}, {'amount': 20, 'category': 'legs', 'info': 'Squats'}]
{'amount': 20, 'category': 'legs', 'info': 'Squats'}
{'amount': 20, 'category': 'legs', 'info': 'Squats'}
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Why class → dict → list in the first place? What's wrong with a list of `Exercises` objects?!

Comment: Why are you calling `__setitem__` explicitly, instead of writing `exercise_dict["amount"] = self.amount`?

Comment: im not that experienced in python, just learning and looking on the internet how to do certain things... so i saw this option and it "worked"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be greatly simplified. You don't need a global `exercise_dict`; you want to create a *new* dict for each object.

```
exercise_list = []


class Exercises(object):

    def __init__(self, amount, category, info):
        e = {}
        self.amount = e['amount'] = amount
        self.category = e['category'] = category
        self.info = e['info'] = info
        exercise_list.append(exercise_dict)
```

or

```
exercise_list = []


class Exercises(object):

    def __init__(self, amount, category, info):

        self.amount = amount
        self.category = category
        self.info = info

        exercise_list.append({'amount': amount, 'category': category, 'info': info})
```

Answer (score 2):

Just recall exercise dict every u call the class

```
exercise_list = []

class Exercises(object):

    def __init__(self, amount, category, info):
        exercise_dict = {}
        self.amount = amount
        self.category = category
        self.info = info
        exercise_dict["amount"] = self.amount
        exercise_dict["category"] = self.category
        exercise_dict["info"] = self.info
        exercise_list.append(exercise_dict)


Exercises(10, "arm", "Arm curls")
Exercises(20, "legs", "Squats")

print(exercise_list)
print(exercise_list[0])
print(exercise_list[1])
```

output:

```
[{'amount': 10, 'category': 'arm', 'info': 'Arm curls'}, {'amount': 20, 'category': 'legs', 'info': 'Squats'}]
{'amount': 10, 'category': 'arm', 'info': 'Arm curls'}
{'amount': 20, 'category': 'legs', 'info': 'Squats'}
```

Comment: ah, thanks for editted @chepner. I didn't see full of code

Answer (score 1):

You always add the same reference to your list. Indeed, you set it, add it, and then modify the same object. When you think about it, a `dict` is an object with attributes. If you were to add an object to your list and modify its attributes, you would expect this behavior.

TL;DR: You have to create another dict before adding it to your list.